# iOS hold and drag within a single touch

Tags: ios

I have a `tableView` and I hope when I long-press a cell, it will add a subview to the top level view and I can drag that new subview all around the screen.

Now I have added a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to the `tableView` and in the long press handle I have added the subview I wanted. But I can't move it around. I added - `(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)` event in the subview class. It worked but I have to do it with 2 taps that is one to add the new subview within the long press handler and another to call the touchesMoved in the subview class.

Any idea how can I do it in a single hold and drag?

Comment: Can you post the code in `-touchesMoved:`?

Comment: @Rickay Sure here's the code in that subview  `code` - (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view.superview];
    self.view.center = location;
}

Comment: I'm not at a computer at the moment as I am out of town, but tonight I'll be back in and I'll take a look. I'm thinking the solution will involve letting touches pass through from the supervise to the subviews so that a touch in the supervise also registers with the subview. I'll let you know what I find out.

Answer (score 0):

Before I did any digging, I thought your question through and it seems that a better way to do what you want is to simply move the code in `-touchesMoved:withEvent:` to your UITableViewCell class. That way the cell is still handling the touches and you don't have to rework the way touches are handled after adding the subview. So:

In your custom UITableViewCell subclass's implementation file:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
    [yourSubview setCenter:location];
}
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thank for your help. I tried it out, and it do handle the horizontal move but only in the cell can it receive the message. Also when I try to move vertically, the touch is received. I'm making an iPad app by the way, and the tableview only fill 1/3 of screen.

Comment: Thanks I get it. Add a long press recognizer and track the move in UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged.